Which interval is $\int^{t^+}_{0^-}$ integrating over?
What do the $+,-$ superscripts in the integral $$\int^{t^+}_{0^-}...$$ mean?
By analogy to one sided limits, I would think it means "integrating over numbers less than 0 and greater than $t$" which of course makes no sense.  If I wanted to describe "integrating over the open interval $(0,t)$," I'd write $$\int^{t^-}_{0^+}....$$
Yet I find this MIT course does it the first way:

How do you explain, or even define, that?  They write

Technical Detail: Because we want convolution to work with delta functions we needed to be careful with the limits of integration. This explains the plus and minus on the limits.. If both functions are continuous
or have at most jump discontinuities then the limits can be 0 and t.

They continue to use this notation several other places.

Parametrize the limits of the integral as $\int_a^s$, then evaluate/define  $\int_{0^-}^{t^+} := \lim_{\substack{a \to 0^- \ s \to t^+}} \int_a^s$

It seems to be suggesting that you include $0$ and $t$ in the interval of integration, though this only matters if $f$ or $g$ include delta functions at $0$ or $t$

@Henry But for the integral to be defined, you must explicitly exclude the $0$ and $t$ endpoints! That's the whole point.

SRobertJames: You asked why they had this peculiar notation.  My comment and @AlkaKadri's comment both suggest that it is explicitly designed to include the endpoints.

A much more self-explaining notation would be $\int_{[0,t]}\dots,\int_{(0,t)}\dots$ and so   on. Those limits remind one of undergraduate calculus (improper Riemann integrals).

This symbol means
$$
\lim_{\varepsilon_1\to0^+\\\varepsilon_2\to 0^+}\int_{0-\varepsilon_1}^{t+\varepsilon_2} f(s)g(t-s)\,\mathrm ds.
$$
However, your problem seems to be that why this notation is necessary. It is because Dirac $\delta$-functions don't behave normally as ordinary integrable functions (in fact, it is not a function, but a generalized function). Thus the integral might be discontinuous w.r.t. the upper and lower bound. For a simple example, note that ($M>0$)
$$
\int_{0^-}^M\delta(x)\,\mathrm dx=1
$$
but
$$
\int_{0^+}^M\delta(x)\,\mathrm dx=0.
$$

Right.  So the OP should show what is in the integrand.  The course cited does say that delta functions may be in the integrand.
